# How much time will for the observer last sound of thunder?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, speed-of-light, acoustics

We have height of the cloud 5 km. The observer stands 20 km away. The speed of sound depends only on the temperature. 
$C=a\times\sqrt T$

Temperature on 5 km is $-33^o C$ and on the ground $7^oC$.

I put inside the temperature difference.

Comment: What do you mean by "height of the thunder"?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: While Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).